# Harmonic mean and arithmetic mean

Tags: sequences-and-series, means, harmonic-numbers

> **Question:** Let a, b, c be three natural numbers. If their arithmetic mean is less than the harmonic mean of $2, 3, 4$ by
>   $\frac{10}{13}$, then find the value of $abc$.

I started the question by making the following equation:
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3} = \frac{36}{13} - \frac{10}{13}$$ and then realized that this equation can't get me far as I need the three terms, $a,b,c$ to be in multiplication. What should I do?

Comment: The harmonic mean of $2,3,4$ is $36/13$, not $13/36$.

Comment: @mathlove Oh yes. My fault, sorry. Typed it wrong.

Comment: You are almost there, so $a+b+c=6$ and $a,b,c$ are positive integers. There are not many possibilities. Indeed there would only be one if you were also told that $a,b,c$ were *distinct* natural numbers.

Comment: @almagest Essentially we go about it through trial and error method? The answer would be 6, I suppose.

Comment: If there are no other restrictions on $a,b,c$ then (ignoring order) you could have $(1,2,3),(1,1,4),(2,2,2)$ with products 6, 4 or 8.

Comment: @almagest Yep I got that. This was a multiple choice question. 6 was the only option given. So... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) of $2,3,4$ is given by
$$
\frac3{\frac12+\frac13+\frac14}=\frac3{\frac6{12}+\frac4{12}+\frac3{12}}=\frac{36}{13}.
$$
We have that
$$
\frac{a+b+c}3=\frac{36}{13}-\frac{10}{13}=2.
$$
By the [inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means),
$$
\sqrt[3]{abc}\le2
$$
or
$$
abc\le 8.
$$
So we know that $abc\le8$ and $a+b+c=6$. Hence, there are a a few possible values of $abc$ that meet the criteria. Suppose that $a=4$, $b=c=1$, then $abc=4$. If $a=b=c=2$, then $abc=8$.